# Converting Decimal Number To Binary In Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, debugging

When I try to convert Decimal To Binary, The code executes with no error but the result is 'none'.
Sometimes it just doesn't show anything.
I feel there is some logical error can anyone help me correct what's wrong??

Code :

```
def bin_no():
    global rem
    
    n = int(input("Enter Number : ")) #Taking a Decimal Num
    
    while n >=1 :   #Initiating a Loop to Convert Decimal To Binary using the (Divide By 2 Method).
        rem = []
        n = n//2
        rem.append(n%2)
        
    if n !>=1:  #Going back to the loop if input is invalid.
        print("Please enter a Valid Number")
        bin_no()

    print("Binary Number : ", rem.reverse()) #Printing the result (the binary no. was stored in reverse order.)
bin_no()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few problems with your code:

1. `rem = []` is inside the while loop, so in every loop iteration `rem` will become `[]` and in the end it will have only the last bit stored in it.
2. The order of `//` and `%` operation is wrong, `//` will first truncate the data and `%` will always produce `0`. You need to reverse the order of those operations.
3. `reverse` is a `list` method that does in place reversal and returns `None`. That's why your code always prints `None`. So, you need to use `rem.reverse()` before the last `print` line and print `rem` normally.

After these changes, your code will look like this:

```
def bin_no():
    global rem
    
    n = int(input("Enter Number : ")) #Taking a Decimal Num
    
    rem = []
    while n >=1 :   #Initiating a Loop to Convert Decimal To Binary using the (Divide By 2 Method).
        rem.append(n%2)
        n = n//2
        
    if n >=1:  #Going back to the loop if input is invalid.
        print("Please enter a Valid Number")
        bin_no()
    rem.reverse()
    print("Binary Number : ", rem) #Printing the result (the binary no. was stored in reverse order.)

bin_no()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a recursive call here. It might produce some troubles.

```
def bin_no()
    n = 0
    while n < 1:
        n = int(input("Enter a Valid Number : "))
    rem = []
    while n > 0:
        rem.append(n % 2)
        n //= 2
    rem.reverse()
    print("Binary Number : ", rem)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can improve on this and add some code comments to explain your solution. First of all, you first check should be `while n < 0:` because 0 can be represented in binary. Ofcourse, your code should take this scenario into account. Secondly, explain the original poster the reason for "some troubles that might arise on using the recursive approach". Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Of course, there is a representation for 0, but the topic starter wants n > = 1 for some reason. Maybe 0 is not suited for him. "some troubles that might arise on using the recursive approach" - is recursion depth constraints. Ok, I'll try to give more detailed answers.